# Undefined function 'fitcnet' for input arguments of type 'string'

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have searched around for this for a long time but seems like nobody has any solution or used this function so called

```
fitcnet()
```

I keep getting the error Undefined function 'fitcnet' for input arguments of type 'string'.

I convert to table, double etc, but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
clear;
close all;
clc

rng('default') 
           


data = readtable('clean_data_nearmiss.csv');



data.Var1 = [];

enter code hesplit_size = 0.15;
N = size(data,1);
split = false(N,1); 
split(1:round(split_size*N)) = true;
permutation = randperm(N); 
split = split(permutation);

trainingSet = data(~split,:); 
testingSet = data(split,:); 

Separating variable predictors and output values for training and test sets.
trainingPredictors = trainingSet{:,1:30}; 
trainingOutcomes = trainingSet{:,31}; 
                                  
testingPredictors = testingSet{:,1:30};
                                    
 testingOutcomes = testingSet{:,31}; 
 X = trainingPredictors;
 y = trainingOutcomes;

neural = fitcnet(X,y,"ClassNames",["0","1"]);
```

Comment: I don't use this toolbox so I am unfamiliar, but it looks like you are giving `fitcnet` invalid arguments (indeed that is what Matlab is telling you). [Documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcnet.html). It looks to me that you can't give it an array of strings, i.e. ["0", "1"].

Comment: hmm, okay. Will see how  I can come around this then. Any suggestion? The reason I use this "fitcnet" is due to the fact that I want to then use "predict" so I can obtain scores. I was not able to find any other function that one can pass to "predict" within neural networks.

Comment: when I remove ["0","1"] it still complains that the function cannot take "double", neither "table" or "string". Strange..

Comment: The documentation says that `fitcnet` was introduced as part of the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox in MATLAB R2021a. What release of MATLAB are you using and do you have that toolbox? If you're on an older version I think that neural network functions are available in the 'Deep Learning Toolbox'.